Problem to keep updated properties of an item after app restart
I created :

A SwiftData container that has been populated with a JSON.
A ContentView showing a list of items and the possibility of picking one of them to show more details in a DetailedView.

ContentView:
@MainActor
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @State private var sortOrder = SortOrder.isFavorite
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var filterFavorites : Bool = false
    @State private var showOldRacquets : Bool = false
    
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                    RacquetList(sortOrder: sortOrder, filterString: searchText, ...)
            ....
                            }
                        }

In the DetailedView toolbar, I want to be able to favorite the item.
struct DetailedView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    var racquet: Racquet
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
                VStack{
                    Text(racquet.name).
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                
                if !racquet.isFavorite  {
                    Button() {
                        racquet.isFavorite.toggle()
                        print(racquet.isFavorite)
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                    }
                } else {
                    Button() {
                        racquet.isFavorite.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    }
                }
                
                if !racquet.isCompared  {
                    Button() {
                        racquet.isCompared.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.metering.center.weighted.average")
                    }
                } else {
                    Button() {
                        racquet.isCompared.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.metering.spot")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

The variable racquet comes from the view RacquetList (called in contentView)
struct RacquetList: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var racquets: [Racquet]



var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
               List {
                                             
                           ForEach(racquets) { racquet in
                               NavigationLink {
                                   DetailedView(racquet: racquet)

the model
@Model
class Racquet {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool

init (id: String, name: String, isFavorite: Bool) {
    
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.isfavorite = false
    }
    
    convenience init(item: RacquetDTO) {
        self.init(
            id: item.name,
            name: item.name,
            isFavorite: item.isfavorite          
       
        )
    }

}



the windowGroup:
        WindowGroup {
            ...
            }
        }
        .modelContainer(RacquetsContainer.create())

the racquetContainer function
actor RacquetsContainer {
    @MainActor
    static func create() -> ModelContainer {
        let schema = Schema([Racquet.self])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        let container = try! ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        /*catch {
         fatalError("could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
         }*/
        
        let myCount: Int = container.configurations.count
        print("\(myCount) ---- \(container)")
        
        
        let listRacquet = CategorieJSONDecoder.decode(from:"db")
        
        if listRacquet.isEmpty == false {
            listRacquet.forEach { racquet in
                let racquet = Racquet(id: racquet.id, name: racquet.name, isFavorite: racquet.isfavorite)
                                               
                container.mainContext.insert(racquet)
                print(racquet.name)
                
            }
            
        }
        return container
    }
        
}

The functionality works, but the favorites disappear if I restart the app.

How do you assign a value to var racquet: Racquet and where does it come from? There’s a lot of information missing here.

Hi Joakim, Just add the origin of the variable

That looks correct to me so the issue must be somewhere else.

can it be linked to the modelcontext? or the way I created the container

Unrelated but you don't really need that if/else with duplicate code, you can have only one button with the label Image(systemName: racquet.isFavorite ? "star.fill" : "star")

Your code looks ok to me (apart from the duplicate Buttons).
I assume you have declared a model such as: @Model final class Racquet { var isFavorite: Bool ...} and setup the appropriate ModelContainer.

Yes, I have declared a @Model class Racquet { var isfavorite: Bool } and with init (isFavorite: Bool) { self.isFavorite = false }

Ok I thought about it . But how can I can initiate a Bool ? null or nil doesn't work

I am not sure to understand. in order to init my model, I set self.isFavorite = false. if in my program I change the value to true, it works but I restart the app, it goes back to false

You should really try to post enough code so we can reproduce this issue.

In your init(....)have you tried using self.isfavorite = isfavorite instead of  self.isfavorite = false

Smart idea ! But it didn't work. Problem remains

I just add the function to create the container.

Ok thanks for your help. I found the problem was linked to .modelContainer(RacquetsContainer.create())
The container was being recreated every launch, it was hard to detect because second was much quicker than first launch. in order to solve the issue, I created a variable that check if it is a first time launch or not.
